# DictVectorizer - Is feature order consistently guaranteed with output?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, scikit-learn

I am using DictVectorizer to convert my features similar to [example code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
X = v.fit_transform(D)
X
array([[ 2.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.]])
```

My question is, if I run this code repeatedly, is order guaranteed? i.e. will 'bar' always occur in first column, 'baz' second column, and 'foo' third column

If order is not guaranteed, do you know of an option to force this? This is important, as new unseen data to be passed into a model trained on this format will obviously need the features occurring in same columns.  Perhaps something could be done with the 'vocabulary_' attribute of DictVectorizer.

Cheers,

Steven

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem if you use the `fit` and `transform` methods in the correct manner. First you fit the DictVectorizer to your data, and then you transform the dataset to a sparse matrix. This is done by the `fit_transform()` method you have called. If you have new, unseen data, you can just transform it using the `transform()` method. This will project the new data into the same data structure as before.

This is illustrated by the example code you have linked to:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
>>> D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
>>> X = v.fit_transform(D)
>>> X
array([[ 2.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.]])
>>> v.inverse_transform(X) == [{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'baz': 1.0, 'foo': 3.0}]
True
>>> v.transform({'foo': 4, 'unseen_feature': 3})
array([[ 0.,  0.,  4.]])
```

The final `transform()` call takes new, unseen data, with two features. One of these is known by the DictVectorizer (because it was previously fitted to data that also had this feature), the other one is not. As the output shows, the values for the known feature `foo` end up in the correct column of the matrix, whereas the unknown feature is simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the explanation!  I think I needed a clear head.  The moment I re-read the code it all made sense.